# does Bundle.putSerializable(key, ArrayLis<T>) have size limit

Tags: android, bundle, parcelable

Trying to pass a list of Data (Parcelable) to a activity using putSerializable,

```
ArrayList<Data> dataList = ...;
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable(KEY, dataList);
intent.putExtras(args);
startActivity(intent);
```

app crashes and shows error below if (in my case) size is over 1295.
Does it have limit on the data size?

Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@451d6148 (pid=10151) when publishing content providers

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a limit but there definitely is a limit on the total size of a Bundle. I don't believe they're intending for passing large amounts of data. This doc outlines the recommended ways of passing data to an Activity:

http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3